# HIVE, json format

Tags: hive

I'm working on Hive, I've created a code:

```
create table table_tweet_sentiment stored as orc as select ().....
```

but when I try to execute the clause.... fail!!!

Caused by:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Unterminated string
```

I was trying to use something like that:

```
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties ("ignore.malformed.json" = "true")
```

but I'm using ORC so.... how can I solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be in your JSON data.  Can you show a sample ? 
The json serde **needs one JSON record per line** and if it's not formatted like that, it may give an error like *JSONException: Unterminated string*